# Can I bundle multiple PendingIntents in a Notification Action?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I want to dismiss my notification when an action button is pressed, but the PendingIntents I'm using are unchangeable. Can I bundle pending intents together so that one intent can be fired and the other can dismiss my notification?

Details:

My notification has 3 action buttons tied to it (`reply, like, share`). Only 1 (`like`) of these action buttons has a PendingIntent that goes into my own app.

The other 2 PendingIntents (`reply and share`) are received by another app entirely (and I do not have access to their original Intent data as I copied the pending intent from that other app's notification)

I want to be able to dismiss my notification when the reply and share actions are pressed but their current `PendintIntents` open up their respective apps. How can I do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PendingIntent implements Parcelable, you should be able to store your PendingIntents in the Intent that you send to your activity when the button is pressed.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
Bundle pendingIntentBundle = new Bundle();
pendingIntentBundle.putParcelable("pintent", pendingIntent);
intent.putExtra("pintent", pendingIntentBundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(spaContext, 0, intent, 0);
```

Then grab the bundle and pending intent and rebroadcast it when your MyClass gets it.

Comment: interesting. I'll take a look! I assume I should attach (putExtra) the notification ID of the notification I want to dismiss into this intent as well? Do you have a good example of a broadcast receiver implementation?